# Swift: TableView within Static UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` with about five different static cells. In one of these cells I'm attempting to load a dynamic `UITableView`

In the interface builder I tagged the main **UITableViewController's** `tableView0`, then I tagged the dynamic `tableView1`.

I'm crashing every time I attempt to load the controller. Here is my rough code so far:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    switch tableView.tag {
    case 0:
        return 2;

    case 1:
        return 1;


    default:
        break;

    }
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch tableView.tag {
    case 0:
        return 5;

    case 1:
        return 2;


    default:
        break;

    }
    return 0

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ComboInfoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    if tableView.tag == 1 {


    // Honestly not sure how to configure only the reusablecells, and not affect the static cells


    }
    return cell

}
```

So I need to know if it's possible to embed dynamic tableviews inside static tableviewcells, and how to do that.

Comment: What does the console say on the crash?

Comment: @ad121 terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can determine by experimenting with this, you can't use the same UITableViewController as the data source and delegate of both table views. With a static table view, you're not supposed to implement the data source methods at all. The strange thing is, even if I disconnect the data source and delegate connections between my static table view and the table view controller, that table view still calls numberOfRowsInSection in my table view controller class. If I explicitly set the data source to nil in code, that stops it from calling the data source methods, but the embedded dynamic table view also fails to call them, so this structure doesn't work.

However, you can get around this by using a different object to be the data source and delegate of your embedded dynamic table view. Make an IBOutlet for your embedded table view, and set its data source and delegate to this new object (The class is DataSource in this example, and it's a subclass of NSObject).

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var staticTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dynamicTableView: UITableView!
    var dataSource = DataSource()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dynamicTableView.dataSource = dataSource
        dynamicTableView.delegate = dataSource
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row != 1 {
            return 44
        }else{
            return 250 // the second cell has the dynamic table view in it
        }
    }
}
```

In the DataSource class, just implement the data source and delegate methods as you normally would.

Comment: The error I"m getting is: "cannot assign a value of type DataSource to value of type UITableViewDataSource

Comment: same for delegate, my custom class is a subclass of NSObject

Comment: any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @YichenBman, you need to tell the compiler that you're conforming to those protocols at the top of your class. Like this: `class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: wow I think you've answered one of my other questions. As always thank you very much. Seriously would never have thought to do anything like this.

Comment: This is what i am doing in my app, but I need a best practice advise. What if your dynamic table views need to update each other. Example: If dynamictableview2 has buttons in its cells and when you tap one of these buttons you need to add a new row inside dynamictaleview2. One possible solution is Notification Center, but do somebody have a better solution ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @rdelmar Rightly so. But does this work with `UITableView.automaticDimension`?