# Populating Dynamic Table View inside Static Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I'm developing an app where I have to display a table view as the content of a Static table view cell inside a UITableViewController, but I can't seem to populate it with my array.

Because I have two table views inside a UITableViewController, every time I try to add the Controller as it's data source the two tables contents are conflicted.

Does Someone know hot to bypass this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571751/swift-tableview-within-static-uitableviewcell/29572792#29572792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is quite possible to have multiple table views using the same view controller as data source. There are many complex layout where this could be useful. To prevent your data from getting mixed up, just check which table view is asking for data in all of the data source methods, for example like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourObject *object;
    if (tableView == _tableViewNumberOne) {
        object = [self.yourFirstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
    } else if(tableView == _tableViewNumberTwo) {
        object = [self.yourSecondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
    }

Setup cell ......
}
```

You need references to the two tableviews from where they were created of course

Comment: As a side note, you might want to forget about the UITableViewController and implement this using a standard UIViewController and set it up as the data source for the table views manually. UITableViewControllers are designed to use with a single tableView.