# Dynamic Tableview inside a Static tableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wanna populate a dynamic tableview inside a static tableview cell, by the same class for both of these.
As you can see in the picture under the cell 'GRE Test Information'.

[image: Helping Picture]

I'm using the code inside the the class named as MenuController, which is a tableview controller.

```
class MenuController: UITableViewController,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate        {

@IBOutlet weak var tablle: UITableView!

var items = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    items = ["A  "," BB "]

    tablle.delegate = self
    tablle.dataSource = self

    self.tablle.registerClass(MainTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellNew")
}


// Table Data Source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellNew", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

        print("Aasim Khaan")

        cell.customCell01.text = items[indexPath.row]


        return cell
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

But it's not populating that at runtime, and says

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellNew - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'*

However I'm using the same identifier named as *cellNew* both in the code and storyboard.

Comment: why not establishing  _sections_ instead? your nested idea does not seem offering a pleasant UX at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after astonishing efforts regarding this one, I've found the solution.
Concerning the following:
[Swift: TableView within Static UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571751/swift-tableview-within-static-uitableviewcell/29572792#29572792)

Where the problem solver says : **As far as I can determine by experimenting with this, you can't use the same UITableViewController as the data source and delegate of both table views. With a static table view, you're not supposed to implement the data source methods at all. The strange thing is, even if I disconnect the data source and delegate connections between my static table view and the table view controller, that table view still calls numberOfRowsInSection in my table view controller class. If I explicitly set the data source to nil in code, that stops it from calling the data source methods, but the embedded dynamic table view also fails to call them, so this structure doesn't work.**

**However, you can get around this by using a different object to be the data source and delegate of your embedded dynamic table view. Make an IBOutlet for your embedded table view, and set its data source and delegate to this new object (The class is DataSource in this example, and it's a subclass of NSObject).**

I've modified my code in this way now :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var items : [String] = ["GRE Test Structure ","GRE Score "]

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellNew", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
        cell.customCell01.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}


class MenuController: UITableViewController,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var tablle0: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var tablle: UITableView!
  var dataSource = DataSource()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
      // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

      // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
      // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
      self.editButtonItem()
      tablle.delegate = dataSource
      tablle.dataSource = dataSource
  }

}
```

Now it works exactly fine.

[image: Here is the result shown by a screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad

```
// First Register the UITableViewcell class from nib 
let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "MainTableViewCell", bundle: bundle)
self.tableView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"cellNew")
```

Then Check with below screeshots

**STEP 1**: Select MainTableViewCell from Identity Inspector-Custom Class-Click Class Drop Down arrow.It shows you list.From that you can click the MainTableViewCell

[image]

**STEP 2**:Once you click that it shows the name with selected table view cell.

[image]

Comment: kindly, would you likely to tell me please, that from where do I've to take this sticky bundle value?

Comment: Aasim did you create MainTbleViewCell.swift file?

Comment: I created MainTableViewCell.swift file.Actually it is UITableViewCell.When I create I gave name MainTableviewCell

Comment: Now If you click class dorp down arrow,it shows you MainTableViewCell file.

Comment: As the typecasting of the cell shows there in the code `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("aNewIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell`

Comment: Have you got Aasim Khan?

Comment: as! MainTableViewCell

Comment: It is just customising the cell

Comment: Tell me about the **bundle**

Comment: Delete your MainTableViewCell.swift file.Then create new file.ios->source->cocoa touch class->Type MainTableViewCell in class and your SubClass of must be UITableViewCell.Then click Next.Now it shows you the MainTableViewCell.swift in bundle.Then go Storyboard click uitableviewcell in tableview.

Comment: Then go Identity Inspector->Custom Class->Click Class Drop Down arrow.It shows you list.From that you can click the MainTableViewCell

Comment: O bhai jan .... I'm not talking about the selection of custom cell class created from the drop down, It is already done in regard of me. I want `bundle` for this statement `let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "MainTableViewCell", bundle: bundle)`

Comment: let cellNib = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

Comment: You should type cast the cell

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: Does my answer not help you?

Comment: Yar it's getting disgusting ? Kuch krro

Comment: see this one if you can understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571751/swift-tableview-within-static-uitableviewcell

Comment: I don't know exactly what you have done in your coding.If you send me your project I solve as soon as possible.

Comment: My problem is that I'm using one single **UITableViewController** for two table views. One tableview is static having 5 entries. The other one is dynamic having some variable entries, that I wanna display inside the 3rd entry of my static tableview. There is one UITableViewController named as **MenuController**. Now the **MenuController** crashes in identifying the tableviews and then providing the relevant data sources to the relevant tableview.

Comment: You gave me one link.That is same like your question.Did you follow that steps?

Answer (score 0):

While the existing answers explain *how* you can do this, they don't address *whether* you should do this. From the example you provided, it seems that all you need is a *single* `UITableView` with multiple dynamic cell types. Each cell type can specify its `contentInsets` to indent the content as needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier cellNew - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>
> However I'm using the same identifier named as cellNew both in the
>   code and storyboard.

You're getting this error because you are dequeing/retrieving the prototype cell from the wrong table!

The line in your cellForRowAtIndexPath should be:

`let cell = tablle.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellNew", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell`

Having said that, even once that is working, asking a tableViewController to act as data source and delegate for both a static and a dynamic table causes problems later.