# Tableview Controller with a dynamic tableview in its static cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift5

I have a form inside a tableview controller. The last 3 parts of the form are address textfield, map and a save button. When the user begins typing on the address field a uitableview will slide up covering the map to display different results. When I set the child tableview mapTableview's delegate and datasource to self this is when the problem would start, the screen just displays a white background. I tried different solutions but they don't work. Also tried this one but the data source must be coming from the tableview controller itself.  [Dynamic Tableview inside a Static tableview Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347456/dynamic-tableview-inside-a-static-tableview-cell)

When I create an array of strings in the class Datasource and put the following codes below in my tableview controller, the strings get displayed in the mapTableView.

```
    var dataSource = DataSource() 


    mapTableView.delegate = dataSource
    maptTableView.delegate = dataSource
```

But since the data source must be coming from tableview controller, I tried to put the code below, and many other things as suggested in other posts, in my table view controller but the screen won't display anything, just all white. And I get these errors:

---

**UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window)**

---

**Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a table view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead**

---

```
    extension EditProfileTableViewController {

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return pois.count
      }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellResult", for: indexPath) as! MapTableViewCell

       let poi = pois[indexPath.row]

       cell.textLabel?.text = poi.title
       cell.detailTextLabel?.text = poi.subtitle
       cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

       return cell
     }
 }
```

and in my viewDidLoad

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension;
```

How to correctly put a tableview inside a static tableview cell? Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create another table view controller for the inner table view. Let's call it `MapTableViewController`.
2. Add `Container View` into the static cell in storyboard.
3. Add `Table View Controller` into that container view, set its class to `MapTableViewController`.
4. Put all datasource/delegate methods for `mapTableView` from the `EditProfileTableViewController` into `MapTableViewController`. After that, `EditProfileTableViewController` should have no `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocol methods at all.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for your response. I will try your suggestion.