# Embedded dynamic UITableView is not loading data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have embedded a dynamic UITableView inside a static cell.

I have also created a new data source based on the answer to this question: [Swift: TableView within Static UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571751/swift-tableview-within-static-uitableviewcell)

My problem is that the data for the dynamic UITableView is not loading. Can you help me understand why?

```
class CreateCompanyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblNumberOfUser: UILabel!
    var newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var companyUsersTableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let dataSource = NewUserDataSource(newStakeholders: self.newStakeholders)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lblNumberOfUser.text = "\(newStakeholders.count) Users"
        companyUsersTableView.dataSource = dataSource
        companyUsersTableView.delegate = dataSource
        companyUsersTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        lblNumberOfUser.text = "\(newStakeholders.count) Users"
    }
    
    @IBAction func addNewUser(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueAddNewUsers", sender: sender)
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwindFromSelectSubUsertoAddUserCompany(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
        if  let senderVC = sender.source as? NewUserForCompanyTableViewController{
            print(senderVC.newStakeholder!)
            var newuser = senderVC.newStakeholder!
            self.newStakeholders.append(newuser)
            companyUsersTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}


class NewUserDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate{
    // We keep this public and mutable, to enable our data
    // source to be updated as new data comes in.
    var newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder]
    
    init(newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder]) {
        self.newStakeholders = newStakeholders
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newStakeholders.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let stakeholders = newStakeholders[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "newUserTableViewCell",
            for: indexPath
            ) as! NewUserTableViewCell
        
        cell.lblUsername.text  = stakeholders.fullName
        cell.lblEmail.text = stakeholders.emailAddress
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITableView `dataSource` and `delegate` properties have a weak reference to the `NewUserDataSource` you initialise in viewDidLoad.

As the initialised `NewUserDataSource` doesn't have a strong reference anywhere once `viewDidLoad` completes, the UITableView's `dataSource` and `delegate` get set to nil as they are weak references and won't keep the `NewUserDataSource` in memory.

To fix this, create a class property of type `NewUserDataSource` which will hold a strong reference to the data source.

Something along the lines of:

```swift
class CreateCompanyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    private lazy var dataSource = NewUserDataSource(newStakeholders: self.newStakeholders)
}
```

Just make sure `self.newStakeholders` has values in it before you use `dataSource`

Comment: don't work. after I create new user and trigger unwind segue is not showing new user?

Comment: Arrays are structs, so if you update `newStakeholders` in `CreateCompanyTableViewController`, then `newStakeholders` in `NewUserDataSource` will still have the same items in it as you are not updating its array with the new values. You should call `dataSource.newStakeholders.append(newuser)` in  `unwindFromSelectSubUsertoAddUserCompany` to update the data sources array.